# Unable to load Oracle.DataAccess.dll in server

Tags: .net, odp.net

I'm working on a MVC appliction which retrive the data from Oracle db for that i'm using ODP .NET(Oracle Data Provider for .NET). it is working fine when i'm running from local, but in server throws a error unable to load oracle.dataaccess.dll

Comment: Have you installed ODP .NET on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, .net 3.5 does not work with ODP. see this post 
[Parser Error Message: Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965900/parser-error-message-failed-to-generate-code-exception-of-type-system-data-de)